# how to create foreign key at runtime using Triggers and/or procedures in Oracle environment

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have two tables named as patient and pharmacy. Each patient is uniquely associated with one pharmacy. I want to create the foreign key constraint at run-time between these tables.

```
Create table patient
(patient_Id varchar2(5) primary key,
patient_name varchar2(20));

Create table pharmacy
(pharmacy_Id varchar2(5) primary key,
pharmacy_name varchar2(20);

Create table patient_pharmacy_mapper
(patient_Id varchar2(5) references patient(patient_Id),
 pharmacy_Id varchar2(5) references pharmacy(pharmacy_Id));
```

Instead of writing the "references" at design time, Can I create/delete these foreign key constraints at run-time (when any DML statement fires)?

I know little about creating a trigger where we have to call a procedure with the "Alter table statement".

Comment: You might try achieving that using `Dynamic SQL`, although any DDL command will commit all your transaction changes. Also, why on earth would you want to manipulate with your constraints in your triggers?! Looks like a really bad idea / design to me (unless I'm missing something or lacking some Oracle DB knowledge?).

Comment: I am trying to isolate the tables from each-other for security purpose.

Comment: Here are some links, you might wanna read [Native Dynamic SQL](https://oracle-base.com/articles/8i/native-dynamic-sql), [Coding Dynamic SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_dynamic_sql.htm)

Answer (score 5):

DDL statements automatically commit the transaction. As you are not allowed to commit (or rollback) in a trigger, you can **not** run DDL statements in a trigger (neither with static SQL nor with dynamic SQL)

---

The whole idea does not make sense. The only sane way to do this, is to create the FK constraints *when creating the tables*. You gain no security from delaying this, absolutely none.

Answer (score 1):

Let me just add another vote to the others about this being a Very Bad Idea (tm).  FK relationships enforce fundamental business rules.  They are part of the design, to be implemented when at the same time tables are created.  Any time (and I emphasize *ANY* time) you find yourself wanting to execute DDL at run time, you need to step back, get a cup of coffee, and reconsider.

Answer (score 0):

Like the other statements I also say it is a very bad idea.

Consider, you can [enable/disable](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_7002.htm#i2062565) constraints or you can set them deferred: [SET CONSTRAINT[S]](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10003.htm) 
Perhaps this is a solution for you problem.